# How to configure package.json to run eslint script

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lint, package.json

I am using eslint as a linter for my react project and I would like it to check all of my `.js` files.

I am able to do this through the script:

```
"lint": "eslint back/*.js && eslint backTest/*.js && eslint front/actions/*.js"
```

how can I get it to examine every `.js` file recursively, something like:

```
"lint": "eslint -r *.js"
```

This would save me having to type out each file individually.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

`eslint "**/*.js"` to run on all js files in all the folders recursively (in the current folder)

You can also do: `AnyFolder/**/*.js`

And to ignore a folder: `eslint "**/*.js" --ignore-pattern node_modules/`

Know more at [eslint/command-line-interface](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface)

Comment: I have setup eslint using tern in my eclipse oxygen. It is linting all the files, I have to set it up to only lint *.js files. What can be done here?

Comment: @Colin @Hadrian Doesn't eslint ONLY parse *.js files by default? Also reading docs if you add `.` it suffices to go through all sub-trees looking for js files

Comment: ESLint always ignores files in `/node_modules/*` and `/bower_components/*`. [Documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#eslintignore) **Edit:** Ok, I realized that your answer also ignores node_modules in a child path, my bad.

Answer (score 72):

`eslint . --ext .js` to lint files with the .js extension.

The `.` targets files in the current directory and all subdirectories.

To include other file extensions,
`eslint . --ext .js,.jsx` or `eslint . --ext .js --ext .jsx`.

The [eslint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--ext) covers this option.

Answer (score 7):

To add to TranBrian10's solution, I installed eslint locally, so calling `eslint` in the terminal results in a `command not found` error.

I was able to get around this by using `npx eslint` instead:

```
`eslint . --ext .js` -> `npx eslint . --ext .js`
```

And as GollyJer noted, this won't work for Windows due to the `.` syntax

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the accepted answer is outdated, but by looking at the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/1.0.0/user-guide/command-line-interface),

> By default, it uses .js as the only file extension.

Also, according to a member's [comment](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/1663#issuecomment-70371024) on the project's Github, using `.` equals running in all subdirectories. It seems to me that running `eslint .` should suffice (though it doesn't cover the new ES Module `.mjs` files).