# How to configure package.json to run eslint on js and jsx files

Tags: javascript, regex, eslint, package.json

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307581/how-to-configure-package-json-to-run-eslint-script) works for linting all `.js` files in a project.

How do I lint all `.jsx` files *in addition to* all `.js` files?

I've gotten this to work:

```
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint \"./**/*.js\" \"./**/*.jsx\""
```

However, I think that there is a more succint way to match both `.js` and `.jsx` file extensions.

Comment: There's no need to include `./node_modules/.bin/` in the `scripts` section of `package.json`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eslint has an `--ext` flag which you can use to specify the file extensions you want eslint to look at. So you can do `"lint: eslint --ext .js --ext .jsx"`

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface

Comment: Look awesome. Bu how i can add linting file formats to .eslintrc?

Answer (score 10):

You could also try the following which is working fine on my machine:

```
"lint": "eslint \"**/*.{js,jsx}\""
```